# Why is Kivy UrlRequest callback blocking GUI thread?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have Kivy app with screen that has a download button that downloads and processes various tables of remote data. It all works just fine but the gui is getting blocked in the process as evidenced by a MDSpinner that freezes about halfway through until the download process is completely finished.

The entire DL process is being run in another thread that does not touch the gui so that should not happen.

My troubleshooting has found that the UrlRequest callback is doing the blocking. Even a simple sleep in the callback hangs the GUI!

Any idea why?  Do I need to run the callback(s) in yet another thread?

Since the real code is pretty complex, here is some simple pseudocode to demonstrate the problem.

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from functools import partial
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from threading import Thread
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen 
import time

class myScreen(MDScreen):

    def on_button(self):
        # activate spinner when download button pressed
        self.ids.spinner.active = True
    
        # run sync stuff in new thread
        t = Thread(target=self.sync_thread)
        t.start()


    def sync_thread(self):
        # lots of code here including several async downloads like this:
        download(some_url)
        
        # when all downloads are done, kill spinner
        self.kill_spinner()
        
        
    @mainthread
    def kill_spinner(self):
        # uses decorator to set gui widget from another thread
        self.ids.spinner.active = False


# URLRequest code -----------------------------
def download(self, url):
    cb = partial(mycallback, arg)
    UrlRequest(url=url, req_headers=myconfig.headers, timeout=timeout, on_success=cb, on_error=cb, on_failure=cb)


def mycallback(self, arg):
    # used to process data from each download
    # PROBLEM LIES HERE!  Anything here - even a simple sleep will hang spinner(gui) until finished
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: just a thought - have your mycallback function be one that creates a thread and starts a thread.

Comment: I may have to go down that path but I don't want to kludge it if there is a proper way to fix this. I don't think the library would do this deliberately since the whole point of the library is to allow background tasks.

Comment: I use Kivy a lot and my programs do just a tiny bit of posting to the web.  I use the Requests library and just have that stuff in a different thread from main.  I didn't even know that Kivy offered a web request feature.  now that I know i guess I will not change anything because in my case it wouldn't change anything except to tie my programs features more to Kivy

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the kill_spinner function inside the on_button function. Here even if you have a thread here, you disable the spinner after having downloaded and processed everything which causes the lag.

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from functools import partial
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from threading import Thread
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen 
import time

class myScreen(MDScreen):

    def on_button(self):
        # activate spinner when download button pressed
        self.ids.spinner.active = True
    
        # run sync stuff in new thread
        t = Thread(target=self.sync_thread)
        t.start()
        # when all downloads are launched, kill spinner
        self.kill_spinner()


    def sync_thread(self):
        # lots of code here including several async downloads like this:
        download(some_url)
        
    @mainthread # should be useless
    def kill_spinner(self):
        # uses decorator to set gui widget from another thread
        self.ids.spinner.active = False


# URLRequest code -----------------------------
def download(self, url):
    cb = partial(mycallback, arg)
    UrlRequest(url=url, req_headers=myconfig.headers, timeout=timeout, on_success=cb, on_error=cb, on_failure=cb)


def mycallback(self, arg):
    # used to process data from each download
    # PROBLEM LIES HERE!  Anything here - even a simple sleep will hang spinner(gui) until finished
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: That would just kill the spinner immediately but the spinner is just  the symptom. In my sample code all I do is sleep and don't even bother to kill the spinner but the sleep is enough to hang it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested,

I did get it to work by simply spawning a new thread for each callback task.
Then in my sync thread I keep looping until the callbacks are all done & only then call kill_spinner.

Spinner now runs smoothly all the way to the end.

Still not sure this is Kosher but it does work!